# Hadoop Build failed (Hadoop src 2.2.0) on Windows 7, Maven 3.1.1, Jdk 1.7.0_45

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, build

Though I am running 
**Ms-SDK 7.1** command prompt in **Admin mode**, I am getting ***hadoop.dll access denied error*** causing hadoop build failure.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8
.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-common: ArchiverException: Error whil
e creating archive: Problem creating jar: C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-c
ommon\target\hadoop-common-2.2.0\bin\hadoop.dll (Access is denied)
```

I thought it might be problem with JDK version so I have uninstalled jdk1.7. and insatlled jdk1.6.0_45 but still I'm getting permission error.

Can I simply avoid hadoop-common module and install other?

Answer (score 3):

I just received this same error.

I solved it by adding security permissions to the file and every parent folder in the path back up to the root hadoop folder.

Just right-click on the folder/file you want to give permissions to and go to Properties.  Then click the Security Tab.  Next elect the logged in user and check the box marked full control. click Apply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem building Hadoop for Windows 7, even changing the permissions as suggested previously.

However, **repeating the same steps and using the same versions on Windows Server**, it worked properly.

As Hadoop developers says on the Hadoop Windows building guide [1], they have used Windows Server 2008, and "it is likely to work on Windows 7", but the permissions issue still remains.

[1]: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows#line13 Hadoop 2 on Windows

Answer (score 0):

Me too received this error. Tried giving full control on the root folder but still the problem persisted.

Could fix the issue after running **`chmod -R 777 <hadoop-common-folder>`** from the Windows SDK 7.1

Hope this helps some one.